# How to call another javascript needed in a partial view in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is the code for the partial view?

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Record Incident <small>Please enter important information in the audio...</small></h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <h1> {{instruction}} </h1>
            </li>

        </ol>
    </div>

</div>
```

Input something in the input box:

Submit

Here is the main index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <link href="data:image/gif;" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <!-- Angular JS Library import  -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>




</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular Routing Example</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tutorial"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Tutorials</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#demoWriter"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Demo Writer</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view>

        </div>

    </div>

    <footer class="text-center">

    </footer>

</body>
```

This is the app.js code

```
    // create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })
        // route for the tutorial page
        .when('/tutorial', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/tutorial.html',
            controller  : 'tutorialController'
        })

        .when('/demoWriter', {
            templateUrl : 'demoWriter.html',
            controller  : 'demoWriterController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});

scotchApp.controller('tutorialController', function($scope) {
    $scope.instruction = 'This is the tutorial page.';


      // Load the Google Transliterate API


});

scotchApp.controller('demoWriterController', function($scope) {
    $scope.instruction = 'This is the tutorial page.';



});
```

The problem is that even though the expected view is partially viewed in the expected ng-view section, even after loading I want to call some javascript code. And I want to know, how to include those javascript code in the project. And how to call the javascript so that it will do the expected task. I want to convert the typed text in the tutorial partial view to sinhala. For that here is the expected javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Google Transliterate API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages : "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage : google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                destinationLanguage : [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.SINHALESE],
                shortcutKey : 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled : true
            };

            // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
            // options.
            var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

            // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
            // 'transliterateTextarea'.
            control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
        }


        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
```

In addition to this I have to include this script too

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Can anyone please explain me, where and how I should load the expected javascript code that has to be in that partial view which is called by the tutorialController in the app.js. Please explain me how to complete this task.

Comment: why do you absolutely want to load a script after the view is loaded? Can't you load it before, and just call it after the view is loaded?

Comment: no what I mean is that when I set the default route to the dashboard controller it works and the api loads and the translation happens. But when I change the default route into root, the translation doesn't happens after reaching the link....

Answer (score 0):

Use and ng-init to call a function on the target element. Asuming a textarea needs to be added to transliteration scope.

```
<textarea
    ng-init="addTrnsEngine()"
    id="tweet"
    class="form-control primaryPostArea"
    ng-model="newPost.text"
    placeholder="Say something...">
</textarea>
```

where addTrnsEngine() is a function which adds the element to the google transliterate api.

you could send a send a unique id like in the example above or the tagName and search the document by the corresponding id or tagName. ( addTrnsEngine('tweet') )

example:

```
var addTrnsEngine() = function( targetId ){
    var elem = document.getElementById( targetId );
    //add transliteration on elem here.
}
```